# modx multi languages plugin support

Tags: modx-revolution

I'm new in MOdx.I need multi language support in modx 2.2.6 revolution.

Is there any good plugin or helpful something in modx for multi language support?? 
  any suggestion would be helpful for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been quite a while since I looked at something like this but you can do it using Babel and some setup on the server side: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/2012/04/15/MODX+Multilingual+-+Setting+up+Babel+and+have+a+website+with+multiple+languages

Comment: Dead link: Page not found